# Count how many times a row value exceeds a number in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like below:

```
+-------+------+-----+------+------+
|ID     |r     |r1   |r2    |count |
+-------+------+-----+------+------+
|1      |0.3   |0.75 |0.86  |2     |
|34     |0.1   |0.15 |0.9   |1     |
+-------+------+-----+------+----+--
```

The last column 'count' is what i would like to create. That is the number of times a value greater than 0.75 is encountered for each column across that row, so in the first case it is 2. How can i implement this in pandas? I'd like to add that i have 12 such columns i have added only 3 here for ease.

How can i do this in pandas?

Answer (score 2):

The only difficult part here is to select the right columns:

You can `drop` undesirable columns:

```
df.drop('ID',axis=1).ge(0.75).sum(axis=1)
```

You can `filter` wanted columns:

```
df.filter(regex=r'^r\d*').ge(0.75).sum(axis=1)
```

You can slice your columns by labels or by number:

```
df.iloc[:, 1:4].ge(0.75).sum(axis=1)
df.loc[:, ['r', 'r1', 'r2']].ge(0.75).sum(axis=1)
# or shorter: df[['r', 'r1', 'r2']].ge(0.75).sum(axis=1)
```

All this methods give the same output:

```
0    2
1    1
dtype: int64
```